# Old version of gradle is required error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I had a three year old Android Studio which I just upgraded to the latest version(3.2).

I opened a project and tried to run it, but I got this error:

```
Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly.
```

Then, I saw this in `gradle-wrapper.properties`:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2-all.zip
```

From what I understand Gradle 2.2 is not compatible with Android Studio 3.2.

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.9-all.zip
```

Now however, if I try building again, I get this error:

```
Gradle version 2.2 is required. Current version is 4.9.
```

Why does it ask me for an old version of Gradle?

Comment: Can you upgrade the Android Gradle plugin in your root build.gradle?

Answer (score 2):

There are **TWO** places to be aware of:

- Android Gradle Plugin version.
- Android wrapper version and Gradle version

Each version of Android Gradle Plugin version requires a minimum version of gradle version. For your case, it looks these two versions are not in sync. So, try to modify your files as below:

1. Top level `build.gradle`

   ```
   buildscript {
       repositories {
           ...
       }
       dependencies {
           // This is the Android Gradle Plugin version
           classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
       }
   }
   ```
2. `gradle-wrapper.properties`

   ```
   distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.9-all.zip
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Android studio doesn't support that version unfortunately. My advice is using 4.4, that's last full supported version.